# Working with JButtons (extra help)

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, clickable, invisible

I've recently been working on putting together a program that can track one's success during a basketball game. I have a court diagram set up, and my idea is that after clicking a "make" or "miss" button, you can click a spot on the court and it will chart your makes and misses while keeping tallies of both off to the side. I was thinking the easiest way to do this was to fill the court with a huge grid of buttons (20x20), and when you click one it would change the text to an "x" or an "o" depending on if it was a made shot. I have no problems for creating listeners for the various buttons, but the buttons show up over top of the graphics of the court lines. Making the buttons transparent (which I tried) makes it look a little better, but my ideal solution would be to make the buttons in the grid invisible, yet clickable and able to change its text after being clicked.

I am yet to find such a method or other way to make this happen, so if anyone has any experience or input in creating something that could make it function in this way would help. I guess my ultimate question would be is there a way to make buttons invisible, yet clickable? If there is no simple way to do this (which I fear), are there any other ideas that you have that could make this program function effectively that might not involve buttons?

Thank you very much and any ideas would help me out a lot.

I also think I might note that I have a separate driver from the code, even though it probably does not make a difference.

Comment: You could do this manually with a `MouseListener`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this

For the two buttons, just change the `boolean make`. You'll see why later

```
boolean make = false;

makeButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent){
        make = true;
    }
});

missButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent){
        make = false;
    }
});
```

Then you have your `paintComponent`

```
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g);

    if (make){
        drawOval(whataver are your point requirements)
    } else {
        // draw an x at whatever points
    }
}
```

You can see from above that I made use of the `made` variable

Now to get the location you can do something like this

```
Point p;

courtPanel.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){
        p = e.getLocationOnScreen();
        repaint();   
    }
});
```

You paint component will paint based off those point coordinates.

SO basically, what all the thing I listed above does is:

> 1) When the `makeButton` is pressed, it changes the setting to `made` so when the panel is painted, it gets painted with a circle and an `X` when the `missButtton` is pressed.
>
> 2) I add a `mouseListener to the`courtPanel`becuase everytime the panel is clicked somewhere, that's the point on the floor where is it either painted an`x`or a`circle`

If you want multiple `X` and `circle` painted you do something like this

```
private boolean make = false;
private HashMap<Boolean, Point> points = new HaspMap<>();

makeButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent){
        make = true;
    }
});

missButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent){
        make = false;
    }
});

courtPanel.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){
        if (make) {
            points.put(true, e.getLocationOnScreen());
            repaint();   
        } else {
            points.put(false, e.getLocationOnScreen());
            repaint();
        }

});

protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g);

    for (Map.Entry<Boolean, Point> entry : points.entrySet()) {
        Boolean key = entry.getKey();
        Point point = entry.getValue();

        if (key) {
            g.grawOval(point.getX(), point.getY(), 10, 20);
        } esle {
            g.drawLine(.., .., .., ..);  //draws one half of `X`
            g.drawLine(.., .., .., ..);  //draws other half
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's a great way to look at it, I never thought about it that way but it makes perfect sense! I haven't had much experience with MouseListeners but I definitely can implement what you gave me here and work of off that.  Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The problem with transparent components is, basically, it's next to near impossible to actually click them ;)

Another solution might be to use a `MouseListener` on the component rendering the map and simple make the translation from click point to "virtual grid", which you can then renderer over the top, for example...

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class BaseBallMap {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new BaseBallMap();
    }

    public BaseBallMap() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public static class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public static final int GRID_COUNT = 20;

        private BufferedImage map;
        private List<Point> cells;

        public TestPane() {
            cells = new ArrayList<>(400);
            try {
                map = ImageIO.read(new File("Map.png"));
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }

            addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

                @Override
                public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                    Point p = e.getPoint();
                    if (getMapBounds().contains(p)) {
                        p.x -= getXOffset();
                        p.y -= getYOffset();
                        int col = p.x / getColumnWidth();
                        int row = p.y / getRowHeight();
                        System.out.println(col + "x" + row);
                        Point cell = new Point(col, row);
                        if (cells.contains(cell)) {
                            cells.remove(cell);
                        } else {
                            cells.add(cell);
                        }
                        repaint();
                    }
                }

            });

        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return map == null ? new Dimension(200, 200) : new Dimension(map.getWidth(), map.getHeight());
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            if (map != null) {
                Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();

                int xOffset = getXOffset();
                int yOffset = getYOffset();

                int x = xOffset;
                int y = yOffset;
                g2d.drawImage(map, x, y, this);

                int colWidth = getColumnWidth();
                int rowHeight = map.getHeight() / GRID_COUNT;

                g2d.setColor(new Color(255, 0, 0, 128));
                for (Point p : cells) {

                    x = xOffset + (p.x * colWidth);
                    y = yOffset + (p.y * rowHeight);

                    g2d.fillRect(x, y, colWidth, rowHeight);

                }

                g2d.setColor(new Color(128, 128, 128, 64));
                for (int col = 0; col < GRID_COUNT; col++) {
                    x = xOffset + (col * colWidth);
                    g2d.drawLine(x, yOffset, x, yOffset + map.getHeight());
                }
                for (int row = 0; row < GRID_COUNT; row++) {
                    y = yOffset + (row * rowHeight);
                    g2d.drawLine(xOffset, y, xOffset + map.getWidth(), y);
                }

                g2d.drawRect(xOffset, yOffset, map.getWidth(), map.getHeight());

                g2d.dispose();
            }
        }

        protected int getColumnWidth() {
            return map == null ? 0 : map.getWidth() / GRID_COUNT;
        }

        protected int getRowHeight() {
            return map == null ? 0 : map.getHeight() / GRID_COUNT;
        }

        protected int getXOffset() {
            return map == null ? 0 : (getWidth() - map.getWidth()) / 2;
        }

        protected int getYOffset() {
            return map == null ? 0 : (getHeight() - map.getHeight()) / 2;
        }

        protected Rectangle getMapBounds() {

            return map == null ? new Rectangle(0, 0, 0, 0) : new Rectangle(getXOffset(), getYOffset(), map.getWidth(), map.getHeight());

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: The MouseListener is definitely going to help me out, thank you!